# Set Build to Unstable status if Quality Gates fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I need some help, i am trying to set the build status as "Unstable" if quality gate on sonarqube fail. Find below the configuration i've got so far:

[Stage sonarQube Scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXiRq.png)

I've found this also, but i am not sure how to integrate on my stage above:

```
step {                     
                qualitygate = waitForQualityGate()                     
                if (qualitygate.status != "OK") {                         
                    currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE"                     
                }                 
            }
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance for the support,

Comment: Please include your code in the question, instead of a screenshot of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
timeout(25) {
    def qualitygate = waitForQualityGate()
    if (qualitygate.status != "OK") {
        currentBuild.result = "UNSTABLE" 
    }
}
```

Inspired by [Set the build unstable if sonar Quality Gate is failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61225468/set-the-build-unstable-if-sonar-quality-gate-is-failed)